# How to place another shape behind a square?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, shapes

I'm trying to create a custom shape that has a triangle that overflows on the square left side.

I've tried to use absolute and relative positions to achieve it by putting the square behind it but then it hides the spans on the main square. How can I do it?

[Shape that I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B34IP.png)

My code:

```
        <div class="h-96 p-6 bg-white relative rounded-3xl border-3 border-white shadow-sm transition ease-in-out hover:scale-110">

            <div class="flex justify-between">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-gem text-4xl text-secondary"></i>

                <div class="absolute -top-5 right-8 flex flex-col items-center p-4 bg-blue">
                    <span class="text-purewhite font-semibold text-3xl">25€</span>
                    <span class="text-gray-200 font-semibold">for month</span>
                </div>

                <!-- <span class="text-3xl text-primary font-medium">Base</span> -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

[This is what my current UI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXhz0.png)

Already written in the top

Comment: Can you add the shapes and CSS to your question? It's easier to find a solution when I can see the problem in action

Comment: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/957817/screenshots/14889776/media/76f3c8fba65fa252993847b383c78126.png?compress=1&resize=1600x1200&vertical=top

Comment: @strawberrymilk `absolute -top-5 right-8 flex flex-col items-center p-4 bg-blue` this line does the main square